# Arduino stop RGB fading (3rd party library) at interrupt

Tags: arduino, avr, interrupts

Using the following code, the fading process only stops after a full cycle has been run (as predicted). What would be the optimal way to stop the color cycling when the interrupt is called (so I can switch to another cycling mode)

```
/**
 * RGBController
 * author: peterrus
 * License: Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)
 * rgbled library: https://github.com/msparks/arduino-rgbled
 */

#include <rgbled.h>

static const int kRedPin = 10;    // red channel pin
static const int kGreenPin = 9;  // green channel pin
static const int kBluePin = 11;    // blue channel pin

// Brightest value (intensity) to use for any channel.
static const uint8_t kMaxBrightness = 255;

// Delay between color changes.
static const int kDelay = 3;  // milliseconds

// Create the RGBLED object to control our 3-channel LED.
RGBLED led(kRedPin, kGreenPin, kBluePin);

boolean cycle = false;

void setup()
{
  //modeswitch button
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  attachInterrupt(0, doCycleToggle, LOW);

  // set fading delay.
  led.defaultDelayIs(kDelay);
}

void loop()
{
  if(cycle)
  {
    // Fade through the color spectrum.
    //   red -> violet -> blue -> cyan -> green -> yellow -> white -> red -> ...

    // Red -> red + blue (violet).
    led.fadeChannel(RGBLED::kBlue, 0, kMaxBrightness);

    // Red + blue -> blue.
    led.fadeChannel(RGBLED::kRed, kMaxBrightness, 0);

    // Blue -> blue + green (cyan).
    led.fadeChannel(RGBLED::kGreen, 0, kMaxBrightness);

    // Blue + green -> green.
    led.fadeChannel(RGBLED::kBlue, kMaxBrightness, 0);

    // Green -> green + red (yellow).
    led.fadeChannel(RGBLED::kRed, 0, kMaxBrightness);

    // Green + red -> green + red + blue (white).
    led.fadeChannel(RGBLED::kBlue, 0, kMaxBrightness);

    // White -> red.
    uint8_t mask = RGBLED::kBlue | RGBLED::kGreen;
    led.fadeChannels(mask, kMaxBrightness, 0);
  }
}

void doCycleToggle()
{
  if(cycle) { cycle = false; } else { cycle = true; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by modifying the RGB led library so it listens to interrupts.